# How to CONVERT json data to excel file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, nestjs, exceljs

I'm trying to get excel file of my data as below. However, my code doesn't work. Does anyone know, why? I don't get any result or any error. It just doesn't do anything. This method is in a controller. So I'm calling this method from postman

```
import {Workbook} from  "exceljs";
import * as tmp from  "tmp";

    @Get()
    @Header("Content-Type", "text/xlsx")
    async getExcel(@Response() res) {

        let rows = []

        let data = [{name: "shelly", surname: "shelly"}, {name: "shelly1", surname: "shelly1"},]
          
          data(doc => {
            rows.push(Object.values(doc))
          })

          let book = new Workbook();
          let sheet = book.addWorksheet(`sheet1`);
          rows.unshift(Object.keys(data[0]));
          sheet.addRows(rows)

          
          let File = await new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            tmp.file({discardDescriptor: true, prefix: `ExcelSheet`, postfix:`.xlsx`, mode: parseInt(`0600`,8)}, async (err, file) =>{
                if(err)
                    throw new BadRequestException(err);
                
                book.xlsx.writeFile(file).then(_ =>{
                    resolve(file)
                }).catch(err => {
                    throw new BadRequestException(err)
                })
            })
          })


          res.download(`${File}`)
    }
```

Using nodejs with nestjs framework.

Comment: How are you executing this code?

Comment: @sloppypasta oh there is get() tag as well. And this method is in a controller. So I'm calling this method from postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is basically valid and it works. It has a couple of syntax errors and that's it.

Here is the fixed code with differences related to syntax errors commented on.

```
// Missing imports (possibly just not copy-pasted)
import { BadRequestException, Controller, Get, Header, Res } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Workbook } from "exceljs";
import * as tmp from "tmp";

@Controller('json-to-excel')
export class JsonToExcelController {
  @Get()
  @Header("Content-Type", "text/xlsx")
  // Decorator @Res is provided by Nest to describe Response, not @Response.
  async getExcel(@Res() res) {

    let rows = []

    let data = [{name: "shelly", surname: "shelly"}, {name: "shelly1", surname: "shelly1"},]

    // Array was called as a function. It has method 'forEach' to iterate.
    data.forEach(doc => {
      rows.push(Object.values(doc))
    })

    let book = new Workbook();
    let sheet = book.addWorksheet(`sheet1`);
    rows.unshift(Object.keys(data[0]));
    sheet.addRows(rows)


    let File = await new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      tmp.file({discardDescriptor: true, prefix: `ExcelSheet`, postfix:`.xlsx`, mode: parseInt(`0600`,8)}, async (err, file) =>{
        if(err)
          throw new BadRequestException(err);

        book.xlsx.writeFile(file).then(_ =>{
          resolve(file)
        }).catch(err => {
          throw new BadRequestException(err)
        })
      })
    })


    res.download(`${File}`)
  }
}
```

Was this the issue?